# Cropped square bitmap is out of position

Tags: android, image, bitmap, surfaceview, crop

I want to implement a instagram like photo taking app which crops the picture I have taken to square and rotates it clockwise so it stays portrait. There is no problem cropping the bitmap to square, but the cropping doesn't start from the corner of the photo. (x,y) = (0,0) Left part of the photo is cropped away. I want to crop from the top left corner of the original bitmap. Any help?

Here is the code for taking picture and cropping picture:

**Activity_New_Food.java**

```
public class Activity_New_Food extends Activity {

byte[] byteArray;
ImageView foodPhoto;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_food);

    foodPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anf_foodPhoto);

    byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("FOOD_PIC");
    Bitmap original_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);

    int value = 0;
    if (original_bmp.getHeight() <= original_bmp.getWidth()) {
        value = original_bmp.getHeight();
    } else {
        value = original_bmp.getWidth();
    }

    Bitmap finalBitmap = null;
    finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original_bmp, 0, 0, value, value, matrix, false);

    Bitmap bmp = cropToSquare(original_bmp);
    foodPhoto.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);

}
```

**Here is the photo**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF9QZ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've copied and adapted your code slightly and it does exactly what it looks like it should.
I create a 300x500px bitmap and draw to it with using Canvas. Then I crop and rotate using the same methods as you do. The result is a 300x300px bitmap containing the top 3/5 of the original bitmap rotated 90degrees clockwise.

I notice that in your pictures, the cropped bitmap actually contains regions that don't exist in the original bitmap (the margin line on the left). This is more than a cropping problem, you should make sure that the byte array is encoded properly in the first place...

Add a second ImageView to your layout so you can see both bitmaps side by side to compare.